# How to interpret the loss returned by model.evaluate()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I searched a lot for an answer but wasn't able to find a satisfying one.

If I understood correctly, during `model.fit()`, Keras prints the loss for the last batch to terminal.

If I call `model.evaluate()` on the training set I get the loss value for the whole set.

So, intuitively if I call `model.evaluate()` on a single instance of the training set I should get a value that is a fraction of the value I would get calling `model.evaluate()` on the whole training set. But instead I get a value that is close or even bigger by ~10 times. Any idea why?

Comment: When testing with a single sample I assume you are also setting `batch_size=1` right? It's default is 32 if you leave it unspecified.

Comment: In my case it doesn't change the result, but I also tried with `batch_size=1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I understood correctly, during model.fit(), Keras prints the loss for the last batch to terminal.

Generally speaking yes, but this also depends on your `verbose` parameter; if it is set to `2` you are going to get *one line per epoch*, but if you set it to `1` you are going to get a *progress bar* that gives info on each batch and other things.

This also prints any other metrics you included in your model (like accuracy, MSE, etc.).

---

Now, I think that the intuitive behavior you expected is not quite right. First, I must say that this will also depend on your specific model and architecture, as some features like Dropout Layers could have their own specific interactions that may change the result of your loss and metrics.

The thing is that the `model.evaluate()` method does the calculations **in batches**, as specified in the [docs](https://keras.io/models/model/#evaluate). Two important arguments are `batch_size`, which is the number of samples per evaluation step, and `steps`, which are the number of steps (batches) to finish the evaluation.

Digging a bit on the source code of `model.evaluate()` we can see that **it averages the loss and other metrics returned by the [`steps`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L1412) or [`num_samples`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L1445) of you batch size**.

This means that if you pass only one sample the result you get will be divided by `1` (and get higher values), whereas if you provide more samples (like your test data) the results will be averaged by numbers greater than `1`, thus obtaining "smaller" values than the ones given with fewer samples.

Comment: My `verbose` parameter is set to 2. Right now I'm just experimenting a bit with a simple autoencoder: input, hidden, and output layer. I understand what you're saying but still don't know how to apply to my case. Given that the output of an autoencoder is the reconstruction of the input how do I understand how well it is doing? Also, what kind of distance from the input is loss calculating on the output, in the case of an autoencoder?

Comment: @RiccB aha, Autoencoders are quite different from regular NNs, probably why you get strange results. I wouldn't break my head much on that one; regular or conv networks perhaps would be better candidates to try those things. In any case, *maybe* you should try comparing your losses from your encoded representation

Comment: I'm using mean squared error as a loss function and I can confirm that `model.evaluate()` on a single value is equal to -`sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error(original_value, decoded_value)`. I still need to understand why the values are so weird, but before saying anything else I should standardize the input and see if it changes.